# What's better: return null or handle the Exception?

Tags: java, exception-handling

I'm in doubts what approach to take here, please have a look on the code below:

```
private void processBarCodeResponse(String decodedQrCode) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = JsonUtil.composeJsonObject(decodedQrCode);
        SalePoint salePoint = parseSalePoint(jsonObject);
        if (salePoint == null) return; // handle null value here
        saveSalePoint(salePoint);
    }

private SalePoint parseSalePoint(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        SalePoint salePoint = new SalePoint();
        try {
            salePoint.type = jsonObject.getString("type");
            salePoint.url = jsonObject.getString("url");
            salePoint.salePointId = jsonObject.getString("salePointId");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Logger.logError(TAG, "jsonObject " + jsonObject.toString() + " wasn't parsed " +
                    "correctly");
            return null; // point of concern
        }

        return salePoint;
    }
```

For the sake of readability I moved the `try/catch` block to the `parseSalePoint()` method, but then if parsing fails I'm enforced to return `null` from the method and check for `null` value in `processBarCodeResponse()` method. Wouldn't it be right to just handle the `JSONException` in `processBarCodeResponse()` method and stop its execution once it is thrown?

Comment: This question is on the very edge of being primarily opinion based. I am not voting to close but I am downvoting because of the way the question is formulated.

Answer (score 5):

A possibly useful pattern here can be the [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)-pattern.

Instead of returning `null`, return a "null SalePoint". Perhaps something like `new SalePoint();`, or `new SalePoint("some special url");`. Then make your `saveSalePoint` method do nothing if the SalePoint has a special url indicating that it's null.

Another option is to return `null` from your `parseSalePoint` method as you are currently doing and then simply return from the `saveSalePoint` method if the argument is null which will remove the null check from `processBarCodeResponse`.

Honestly, I can't tell you which option you should use or not. I can only present you with alternatives. Personally I like Null Object pattern a lot, but it doesn't always makes much sense to use that pattern.

By the way, why isn't `SalePoint` immutable? Instead of first creating a SalePoint object and then setting it's values one by one, read the values into variables and call a constructor which takes type, url, salePointId as arguments and get rid of the accessible properties (make them private, and also get rid of the setter-methods if you have any)

Comment: Simon, `SalePoint` object is just a DTO, it encapsulates values parsed from a `String`, I don't even have getters and setters for it, just public variables in it, that's all. What benefits could I get if I made it immutable?
I can't use Null Object pattern because as I said `SalePoint` does nothing.

Comment: @Eugene Do you have any benefit from *not* having it immutable? You *could* refactor to make a `save` method inside your `SalePoint` object so you call `salePoint.save(possibleAdditionalParameters)`. It's up to you of course, I don't know all your code and even if I did I can't tell you how to do it, I'm just saying what you *could* do.

Answer (score 4):

I think the right thing to do would be to move the exception handler into `processBarCodeResponse()`.

```
private void processBarCodeResponse(String decodedQrCode) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = JsonUtil.composeJsonObject(decodedQrCode);
    try {
        SalePoint salePoint = parseSalePoint(jsonObject);
        saveSalePoint(salePoint);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // You don't need to call .toString() explicitly
        Logger.logError(TAG, "jsonObject " + jsonObject + " wasn't parsed correctly");
    }

}

private SalePoint parseSalePoint(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
    SalePoint salePoint = new SalePoint();
    salePoint.type = jsonObject.getString("type");
    salePoint.url = jsonObject.getString("url");
    salePoint.salePointId = jsonObject.getString("salePointId");
    return salePoint;
}
```

Your brace indentation was a bit weird; I hope that was just a result of pasting the code into this website.